# What browsers should I consider in designing a website?

Tags: css, mobile, browser, version

In regards to the number of users, what browsers and browser versions are worth considering in creating new websites for both mobile and desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is highly subjective, depending on your market. However, I would suggest using the tables at http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html to help you make that decision for yourself. You need to carefully consider the geographic location of your target market, the features you need to support, the amount of traffic you expect now and in the future, what browsers are used by default on different systems and devices your users will be using, and many other factors (i.e., as browser usage trends), when making this decision.